# Prevent VBA from duplicating dropdown list selections when entering manual text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data-validation

I'm using a VBA code for a dropdown list with multiple options in Excel, but when I enter text manually in a cell that already contains one or more selected options, the code duplicates the previous selections and then adding the new text. For example, if I select "Option 1" and "Option 2" from the dropdown list, the cell displays "Option 1, Option 2". However, if I then type "text" in the same cell and click on another cell, the cell displays "Option 1, Option 2, Option 1, Option 2, text".

I'd like to modify the code to prevent this behavior and maintaining the selections **Option 1**, **Option 2** with the new **text** when the cell is edited manually. Here's the current code I'm using:

```
Option Explicit 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)
Dim rngDropdown As Range
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim DelimiterType As String

DelimiterType = ", "
 
If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
 
On Error Resume Next
Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitError
 
If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
 
'Check if the cell has data validation or not
If Destination.Validation.Type = xlValidateList Then
    If Intersect(Destination, rngDropdown) Is Nothing Then
       'do nothing
    Else
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      newValue = Destination.Value
      Application.Undo
      oldValue = Destination.Value
      Destination.Value = newValue
        If oldValue <> "" Then
            If newValue <> "" Then
                If oldValue = newValue Or _
                    InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue) Or _
                    InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                Else
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
 
exitError:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me modify this code to achieve the desired behavior? Thanks in advance for your help!

---

I apologize for needing to provide further clarification about my situation. In data validation, there are multiple options available, including "cm width," "cm length," and "cm depth." Once I have chosen an option from the multiple data validation list and entered a measurement into the cell, I would like to append a text string to the cell. For example, if I select "**cm width**" and input a measurement of **20**, and then select "**cm length**" and input a measurement of **30**, I would like the cell to display "**cm width 20**" and "**cm length 30**," respectively. *I want to avoid any repetition or duplication* of the string, such as "**cm width**," "**cm length**," "**cm width 20**," and "**cm length **30**."

Comment: Welcome! *However, if I then type "text" in the same cell* - do you mean **add the word *text* to the existing string**? Just change your behavior - do not add a word, but enter it instead of an existing line, completely replace the existing text "Option 1, Option 2" with the word "text" and see result